# Javascript fail to redirect after firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm authenticating users registered in my firebase database and i want to redirect the user after successful authentication

```
const txtEmail = document.getElementById('email');
const txtPass = document.getElementById('password');
const loginBtn= document.getElementById('reg');
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const mail = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPass.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pass);
  if(promise){
    window.location = "{{ route('users') }}";
    console.log("{{ route('users') }}");
  }else{
  }
});
```

the log is successfully printed but the redirection fails may someone help

this is my form i don't know but maybe there is something wrong in it

```
<form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" required="" id="email" placeholder="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" required="" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-custom">
                                <input id="checkbox-signup" type="checkbox">
                                <label for="checkbox-signup">
                                    Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-30">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred btn-block waves-effect waves-light" class="reg" id="reg">
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group m-t-30 m-b-0">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <a href="page-recoverpw.html" class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-lock m-r-5"></i> Forgot your password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Try using the `assign` function instead: `window.location.assign("{{ route('users') }}");`

Comment: it didn't work to.

Comment: What's the actual value of `route('users')` ?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/users

Comment: Can you try using `window.location.assign("http://localhost:8000/users");`?

Comment: i've just tried it but not working to, it's confusing thing.